# How to remove "$" and "." with regex

Tags: regex, string, substring

i'm currently web scraping  an ecommerce website which i am choosing the prices of the products. The price follows this format:

> $4.500

And i currently have this in the regExr of the web scraping software:

```
[0-9]+\.[0-9]+
```

I'm currently just looking how can i remove the dollar sign and the dot? To leave it like this

> 4500

What i understand from regex is that i can match the $ and . character. So i tried it on [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/) this:

> \$[0-9]+.[0-9]+

What is the regex so i can match certain characters and delete them?

Comment: Regex does not delete anything, regex *matches* or *does not match* some existing continuous pieces of text. You can't match disjoint pieces of text within one regex matching operation.

Comment: You could make use of capturing groups `\$(\d+)\.(\d+)` https://regex101.com/r/11VNvi/1

Answer (score 1):

```
String s = "$4500";
s = s.replace("$", "");
s = s.replace(".", "");
```

Answer (score 1):

In JavaScript, this can be done in the following way (if you still want to use regex):

```js
const [dollarSymbol, ...values] = /\$([0-9]+)\.([0-9]+)/.exec('$4.500');
const result = values.join('');
```

or a shorter way would be:

```js
'$4.500'.replace(/[$.]/g, '');
```